# Merge [formula] and [formulas] tags

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

[formula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formula) × 2
[formulas](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formulas) × 2

I suggested a synonym 'formulas' → 'formula'. Please [vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/formula/synonyms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'formula' is now remapped to 'formulas'.

Answer (score 3):

I think that for consistency, we should have tags in plural form. Another way to think about it, is to fill in the blank: `This question is about <tag-name>.`

For this reason, I think `[formula]` should be merged into `[formulas]`.

Note: for some of the other synonyms I suggested, I wasn't able to choose the plural form as the master tag, so I chose the singular form. Once one of these have been approved, I would recommend that a mod change it to its plural form for consistency.

It's a good spot anyways, so thanks for the suggestion. One other thing to note is that only 5 of us at the present time have enough reputation (2500) to vote on the synonyms.

Comment: I don't have strong feelings either way, so long as we're consistent.