# Merging tags [book] and [books]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Both tags, [*book*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) and [*books*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) refer to the same thing and thus should be merged. As stated in this comment: [Merge 'formula' and 'formulas'](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/718/merge-formula-and-formulas/726#726) probably they should be merged to *books*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been done and a synonym created for `book` > `books`