# Burninate [books]?

Tags: discussion, tags

**UPDATE** Sterling work by @[ale](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/ale) and there are at present no Qs with this tag, so the issue is 'moot'.

---

Tag [books](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) lacks a Usage guide and has no followers but is currently applied to <strike>7</strike> 1 Open Q:

<strike>[How to make multipage book in Calameo?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30108/how-to-make-multipage-book-in-calameo)</strike>

<strike>[Does Amazon change previewable pages of a book according to some factors?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76753/does-amazon-change-previewable-pages-of-a-book-according-to-some-factor)</strike>

<strike>[How can I download a Picaboo photobook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60855/how-can-i-download-a-picaboo-photobook)</strike>

<strike>[Saving on shipment costs when buying several books](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69735/saving-on-shipment-costs-when-buying-several-books)</strike>

[How to save HQ book cover images on Amazon](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/how-to-save-hq-book-cover-images-on-amazon)

<strike>[How to check if a Google Books item is in the public domain without API?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73065/how-to-check-if-a-google-books-item-is-in-the-public-domain-without-api)</strike>

<strike>[How to resurrect one's Amazon Reading List data in Shelfari?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41422/how-to-resurrect-ones-amazon-reading-list-data-in-shelfari)</strike>

Other tags with "books" in them (excluding Facebook ones):

[google-books](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-books), [ebooks](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebooks), [google-play-books](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-play-books)

Related: [Merging tags [book] and [books]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/850/merging-tags-book-and-books)

Regarding Shog9’s criteria for burnination, summarised as:

```
    - Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?
    - Is it unambiguous?
    - Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
    - Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
    - Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
```

IMO the As are, in order: No, No, Possibly, No, No.

Would anyone care to speak in its defence in a trial for its life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[books](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) and [ebooks](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebooks) in the context of Web Application they are meta-tags as they can't be used without any-other tag.

Related discussion: [In the context of Web Applications, which are the tags that are not specific to a web application that are not meta-tags?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3986/88163)

Comment: [tag:books] and [tag:ebooks] have been cleared of questions.